# Emulating static variables using prototype

Tags: javascript

```
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.population = 0;
Person.prototype.constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log("Name: " + this.name);
    console.log("Population: " + (++this.population) );
}

var p = new Person("Wex");
```

The following code doesn't seem to work, although logically I feel like it seems sound. How come this doesn't display the name and population?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/gvjEF/

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log("Name: " + this.name);
    console.log("Population: " + (++Person.population) );
};
Person.population = 0;

var p = new Person("Wex");
var p = new Person("Wex");
```

As long as you want static class variable you need:

1. define it as `classname.varname`
2. use it using the classname, not `this`
   ​

Comment: You were right. Next time be a little more civil. Have a good day.

Comment: Is there any way to access `Person.prototype.population` other than by using `this.constructor.prototype.population`?

Comment: @Wex: for what reason? Static variable should be accessed via `classname.varname` without any `this`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xrcD9/ - this is what I'm talking about. How is this different?

Comment: @Wex: there is no major difference, but adding `prototype` makes no sense for static variable. As long as it is static - it belongs to the class, not to the instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Person() {}
Person.staticProperty = "foo";
var obj = new Person();
```

staticProperty is defined in Person object, which is the function.